# List of jsons to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

I have been appending multiple JSON files to a list and exported that list as file named 'Merged_file.json'. Now I am having trouble converting the list of JSON objects to a Pandas data frame. The data set looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "ids": {
        "parts": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "8"
        ]
    },
    "process": true,
    "indexes": [],
    "metadata": {
        "m_13": {
            "description": "This is a test",
            "confidence": {
                "state": "pre-added",
                "who": [
                    "user:George"
                ],
                "prob": 1
            }
        }
    }
  }
]
```

How can I extract the 'metadata' object and all the different values it holds into a Pandas dataframe?
Before I appended the results to lists, I could simply extract the columns using json_normalize, and had a working code like this. Can anyone help with this specific example, or should I append to something else than a list?

EDIT:
Expected output:

```
Index    |Description     |State      |Who 
0         This is a test   pre-added   George
```

- So I want to take the values from different nested objects. This is just the first of the 'metadata'. Imagine having a structure like this for 12 more.

Comment: can you show the code you've tried.. Also there are scores of similar related Qs here. How's this Q different then?

Comment: @maverick What code are you thinking about? The appending to list code or the extraction code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `json_normalize` you can do this:

```
with open('1.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, 
                       record_path=['metadata', 'm_13', 'confidence', 'who'],
                       meta=[['metadata', 'm_13', 'description'],
                            ['metadata', 'm_13', 'confidence', 'state'],
                            ['metadata', 'm_13', 'confidence', 'prob']])
print(df)

             0 metadata.m_13.description metadata.m_13.confidence.state metadata.m_13.confidence.prob
0  user:George            This is a test                      pre-added                             1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution did it :D